# Auto Populate "Related To" field to an Account upon Event creation

Tags: activities, automation

I have searched throughout the internet and have found no real answer to this: How can i have an Event auto populate "Related to" with a specific account, only upon initial record creation and if blank. This will allow all events to be visible by all users. I was surprised i could not see this in workflow rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workflow rule couldn't do this, but you could do it in the Process Builder.

I suggest you try out the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/business_process_automation/units/process_builder) for more details.

[image: Event Related To in Process Builder]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out thank you. i just had to change null to true. simple mistake. i also used the Related To ID found in the URL on the Account i wanted to use.

Thanks!